# Puedo poner el doodle de Google en el buscador de mi pagina web?

Tags: html, html5

Esta es mi página web: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y me gustaria meter el doodle de Google y que se actualize con el tiempo, habría alguna forma de hacerlo?, mientras yo tengo una imagen.png de google pero quedaría mejor con lo que os cuento.

aquí dejo lo que es un doodle: (y la pagina donde estan recopilados todos: https://www.google.com/doodles?hl=es)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Las políticas de google no te permiten hacer un embed de sus dooles, 
te adjunto el parrafo en el que lo explican:

> Doodles de Google
>   Los doodles (o logotipos ilustrados) se muestran durante todo el año en la página principal de Google. Hemos creado una galería en la que puedes disfrutar de los doodles, **pero normalmente no permitimos que terceros los utilicen**. Asimismo, tampoco permitimos que los usuarios creen y publiquen sus propias versiones del logotipo de Google.

[Enlace a las políticas de permisos de google](https://www.google.com/permissions/using-the-logo.html)

Comment: Muchas gracias, no había visto la politica de los doodles

Comment: habrá manera de replicar el código, no exacto pero que tenga el mismo efecto